# XText validation keeps loading and no response in Eclipse while editing Cucumber Feature file

Tags: validation, editor, xtext, feature-file, no-response

I am using Eclipse IDE. BDD project(Cucumber-Java-Selenium). While editing the feature file, I am facing the issue. The Tool stops loading and goes to "no response" state while editing the feature file. It is back after several minutes(say 10-15 minutes)

Comment: you should take some jstacks to see where the time is spent.

Answer (score -1):

I got the solution. @christian, thanks for your interest. I'm not sure what is jstack mean here...
I got the solution because, I had Natural installed in eclipse, because of which cucumber editor has taken as editor for feature file. I have changed it to feature editor as default for feature files in file association and that has taken the effect.